# Does adding a reference to a shared ptr increase the reference count

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Suppose I have a method as such

```
void foo(const boost::shared_ptr<Pfoo>& rx)
{
   myvector->push_back(rx);
}
```

I read that when a boost::shared_ptr is passed as a reference its reference count does not increase. Now what would happen in the above scenario if the actual ptr ran out of scope ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When pass pointer by reference - no copy occured, no reference-counter incrementing.

```
myvector->push_back(rx);
```

Here, in vector will be pushed copy of `rx`, not `rx`, so, reference-counter will be incremented.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass by reference you pass the same pointer - no copies occur. So the lifetime of `rx` is bound to the lifetime of the original object. When you do `push_back` container will do copy of `rx` and so increase ref count.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. If you pass a reference to a shared pointer, the function only gets a (regular C++) reference to the caller's (shared) reference. It does not get its own (shared) reference. If the caller's (shared) reference is destroyed, the code fails.

This happened to me once and caused a serious bug that was difficult to track down and had real consequences. So don't pass references to objects unless you are sure nothing the function does can have the effect of destroying the referenced object!

The `push_back` creates a new reference to the object.

Answer (score 0):

No. Below code just passes the smart pointer to the function and will not increase reference count of it:

```
void foo(const boost::shared_ptr<Pfoo>& rx)
```

Also, pushing `rx` to the vector will increase the reference count:

```
myvector->push_back(rx);
```

Answer (score 0):

smart_ptr is passsed as reference so it wont increment ref count at that time.
In case of vector copy of object is inserted . So the reference will be incremented .

```
myvector->push_back(rx); //Copy of object is passed.
```

Comment: You mean if a copy is made reference will be incremented